# dual boot: SSD Windows 10 UEFI + HDD Ubuntu 18 legacy boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a dual boot with SSD Windows 10 UEFI + HDD Ubuntu legacy.

I can boot both OSs correctly using BIOS boot order.

Windows does not appear in the grub entries. I tried OS-Prober and `grub-update`, but it didn't work.

I added a custom Windows 10 menu entry to 40_custom.cfg using `blkid` to find the uuid of the windows 10 UEFI partition, but when selected in the grub menu: `no such device found`.

How can I fix this?

`lsblk` output:

```
loop0    7:0    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop1    7:1    0  86,6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop2    7:2    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop3    7:3    0   3,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop4    7:4    0   1,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop5    7:5    0  12,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931,5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   499M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0    99M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0   223G  0 part
```

Comment: Hi Nano, welcome to askubuntu! Include the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `etc/default/grub` and `blkid` to your post. Further the `40_custom` file is without the **.cfg** extension. Add your `/etc/grub.d/40custom`file to your post. Did you made a `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Best to re-install ubuntu with uefi boot, i.e., backup data, re-install, then restore data. It's harder to change windows 10 from uefi to legacy and I won't recommend that. I think windows 10 comes with a utility to change from legacy to uefi but not vice versa.

Comment: @abu_bua I will edit post when I can, ty

Comment: @Bernard Wei But I think it is possible ot have a dual boot mixing legacy and uefi, am I wrong ?

Comment: @NanoPish Only via UEFI Bios boot selection with legacy support. I don't think it can be done from Grub or Windows bootloader, which is what you wanted right?

Comment: @BernardWei Yes it is what I want. I may be wrong but I remember managing to make this kind of setup work with grub.

Comment: @NanoPish I have a desktop with mix legacy (Windows) and UEFI (clover+mac). The only way I found possible to switch between the two is via bios boot. Untill I change windows 10 from legacy to UEFI, microsoft have a tools for this. If you can find a tool to do this for Ubuntu installation, that's probably your best bet.